# Client to client messaging in socket programming

Tags: c++, sockets, client, server

I'm working on a project which is a server-client application based on WinSock in C++. I've done whatever needed for communicate between the server and the client that I am able to send and receive messages between them.

Now I need to know how to accomplish the client-to-client messaging part and how the work must be done. I only know that for instance if Client A and Client B need to communicate with each other, the client A must send the message to the server, server receives the message and send it to client B.

If this is the proper approach please help me to know how the server should know anything of of the receiver (which is the Client B in this case)?

Please let me know if I haven't explained clearly my problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The way I did it was that every time a client connects to the server, I give that client a unique ID. Whenever another client wants to send a message, it sends the Receiver's UniqueID and the message. The server sends that message to the client with the ID the message was intended for. I had a function for "polling" the server for clients. Everytime a client connected to the server, I sent a command to each client to update their online-list. When a client disconnects, it sent a command to each client to update their list.. basically like msn-messenger.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. But when you say "Whenever another client wants to send a message, it sends the Receiver's UniqueID and the message.", do you mean it sends two different messages one for Receiver's UniqueID and one for the message or the message has to have the both information and what the format of the message should be?

Comment: I made my own format. It went like this:  struct CMsg {unsigned long ID, Length, Command; char* Message;};  I wrote the struct into a byte array and sent that across to the server. Server reads the ID (sizeof(unsigned long)), then the Length, then the Command. Finally, it reads "Length" amount of chars (the message).

Comment: @Brandon Thanks you. your explanation helped me a lot. But I have another question. I'm not sure I can ask it here or I should open another question. I need to know if I want to write another client app in another platform like android, what message can be sent from the client? How can we access to CMsg struct from java?

Answer (score 7):

One way to accomplish this is have one of the client to act as a server after some communication over actual server. You need to create a protocol of yours. That being said:

1- Client A: -Hey, Server!. Tell the Client B to create a comm server so I can communicate directly with him.

2- Server: -Hey, Client B!. Start a server instance and tell me the connection properties so i can relay it Client A, so he can connect to you.

3- Client B: -Hey, Server!. I'm ready to accept the connection request for Client A. Here's my connection properties...

4- Server: -Client A!! Here the connection properties of Client B. Take it or leave it... I'm done..

5- Client A: -Hey, Server B!.. Can i connect?..

That is the protocol.. So any client first initiates a request to server that includes the message type of "me, requesting to connect to client x..". Server commands the client x, client x responses, server relays the response to initiator client... And also you should implement the error handlings, denial policies or some other things you can think of in order to manage the whole protocol.

Comment: If neither client can start a server (poking a hole in whatever firewall they are behind) then it may be impossible to route messages client to client.  In this case there are some dirty tricks you can try (send UDP packets from both ends and see if you can then receive "replies"), but there's no really guaranteed solution.

Comment: @Speed8ump UDP packets are evil! :)) Client B can say "server, i'm not able to create a comm server" at stage 3 above and server can relay "client a, client b is unserverable to you.." at stage 4. Or if client b is able to start a server but if there is a firewall, the server can test the conn. properties of b's after stage 3, and instead of saying "here the props" at stage 4, he can say "client b is up but isn't connectable" to client a.. And yes, there is no guaranteed solution to this. That is why the protocol should be managed very well..

Answer (score 3):

1. Client A talks to server.
2. Client B talks to server.
3. Server determines A needs to talk directly to B and vice versa.
4. Server sends A and B a message which contains details of how to talk to each other (IP address, ports, etc).   Message also details which (A or B) will initiate contact, timeouts, etc.
5. Upon receipt, each A and B start listening on ports detailed by server.
6. Whoever was setup in the message to initiate contact, does so (A talks to B or vice versa).

Unless I totally missed the point of the question.   You need to define a couple new messages with all the details needed for A and B to talk and send it to both A and B and they need to receive/process the message and react accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Think the client-server communication as an old Radio communication.

1. A needs to talk with B, so B must be listening
2. A finishes his speech (you just send a keyword, something like '//EOC',  or use a fixed width for messages ).
3. B needs to talk with A, so A must not be talking, to let B talk to A

iterate until end-of-communication command

so just imagine that talk is `write`, and listen is `read`

```
 B:  read  -> A:  write 
 A:  read  -> B:  write
```

remember to use a keyword to disconnect the 2 clients, or you could have some bad behaviour from the system calls