# Client to client communication in socket programming with a lot of clients

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, client, server

I'm developing a chat application using c#. I've done everything needed for communicating between the server and the clients however, I'm not sure what to do so that the clients to be able to communicate to each other.

I've searched over the internet a lot. I've actually asked pretty much the same question before.

[Client to client messaging in socket programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531503/client-to-client-messaging-in-socket-programming)

Now I know there is two approach for the job to be done.

The first one is the direct client to client communication in which one of the clients acts as a server for the other one however it has some disadvantages due to the system firewall which may prevents the client to act as a server.

The second approach is to let the server does the communication by receiving the message from one of the clients and send it to another. I personally prefer this one because I think it must be more reliable and we can be absolutely sure that the message will be sent and received. Please let me know me if I'm wrong.

However the problem which I have is that I don't know how the client should let the server know about the other client to whom he wants to communicate.
To be more specific, let's say client A wants to talk to client B. So he sends his request to the server with the username or the IP address of the client B. Now, How the server should find the client B? Does it have to keep a list of clients and search for client B using a for statement for example? What if the there are hundreds or thousands or even hundred thousands of clients connected to the server?

Please let me know if I haven't clearly explained my problem. Any help is appreciate.

Comment: You seem to have all the answers in your question. You're following the needs correctly. You'll have to track each client. If the server has hundreds of thousands of connections, you should start looking at some kind of load balancing probably.

Comment: Though the question is broad but very authentic and correct to ask. It addresses a problem which anyone can face, coupled this he asked in a very precise way as well, I dont know why this thread is closed for further discussion.

Comment: I think this thread must have been left open. I chanced upon it searching for a similar solution, but I could also offer a useful answer to this particular question. If discussions were open, this could have helped a lot of people constructively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario the server has to keep a list of the clients connected to it. Here is how it should work:

1. Client A connects to server
2. Server sends Client A list of clients, available for him
3. Client A sends server the name(or some id) of the client it wants to send a message to(Client B), together with the message
4. Server sends client B message

Comment: I suppose your answer is much more relevant. Of course the server should send the list of clients connected to it and available to the client A. for example the clients who are currently in the chat room in which the client A is. Let me know if I've got your idea correctly.

Comment: A more feasible way would be to implement a mechanism where clients register their services with the server after they connect. Then, when any client needs a service, it could just pass a request for the service to the server (with required params etc), and the the server could route the request to the servicing client, and the responses back to the requesting client. This eliminates the need for each client to know about all other connected clients, and about the services each is willing to provide. Unfortunately this thread is closed, else this would have been a more elaborate answer.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with one central server sounds right. As a general idea - the server should keep a list of all clients connected to it. And then when the client A wants to message client B, it then sends a message to the server specifying which other client the message should reach.